# How do I configure WCF for a callback web service over http transport

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, soap-client

I have a Java asynchronous web service, which I think it works differently to most web services.

```
Client: Send Request
Server: Send synchronous reply (acknowledge message)
Some time later
Server: Send asynchronous reply (data message)
```

I imported the WSDL. I set up the endpoint with a wsDuelHttpBinding. This did not work. Then I tried a custom binding

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="CustomBinding">
    <compositeDuplex clientBaseAddress="http://10.0.0.15:5555/"/>
    <oneWay packetRoutable="true" />
     <customTextMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" mediaType="text/xml" />
    <httpTransport />
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

I modified the Microsoft example for CustomTextMessageEncoding, and this helped me get past some of the problems, by fooling with the WS addressing headers that the service does not understand. These headers is required by something in the client stack.

Current problem is that the acknowledge message that is sent by the server, throws the following exception.

> A response was received from a one-way send over the underlying
>   IRequestChannel. Make sure the remote endpoint has a compatible
>   binding at its endpoint (one that contains OneWayBindingElement).

What is an alternative to the `<oneWay/>` channel?
The server code is not in my control.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but a search on the error message turned up the following series of posts that may be of help to you:  [Making One-Way HTTP Requests, Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2006/08/17/702186.aspx)

Comment: @Tim Thanks, I browsed over that post previously and didn't think it was helpful for my problem, but investigating it a bit more, makes me think it might help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I could get this to work was to have both a WCF server and WCF client on the client side.

First I downloaded the WSDL from the service, and made two copies. I edited the one WSDL so it only have requests from the service with the 'ACK' reply I get, I removed all the other `<wsdl:operation/>` elements. From this I created a WCF client. I edited the other WSDL so it only has the async reply operations and created a WCF service from this.

WCF client part of the client does the following

```
Client: Send Request
Server: Send synchronous reply (acknowledge message)
```

WCF server part of client handles this

```
Some time later
Server: Send asynchronous reply (data message)
```

The bindings for both client and service is now just basicHttpsBinding.